# I'm getting upper-level folder zipped along with content of the folder

Tags: osx, directory, zip

I made bash script to automate process of packing browser extension in `.zip` archives, but for some reason, beside content from the current directory (`public` folder, `manifest.json` and `index.html`) it also packs `mcm_extension` folder (upper folder) along with current folder in it and whole content from it again. Therefore I finish with:

```
mcm_extension/
-{current folder name}/
--public/
--manifest.json
--index.html
public/
manifest.json
index.html
```

Instead of

```
public/
manifest.json
index.html
```

in `mcmc.zip` and `mcmf.zip`. Here's the script:

```
# Removes .DS_Store files from a project
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch

# Creates directories of extension if they don't exist already
mkdir -p ../mcm_extension && mkdir -p ../mcm_extension/mcmc && mkdir -p ../mcm_extension/mcmf

# Google Chrome
cp -R /Users/apple/Development/mcm/public/ /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmc/public/
cp /Users/apple/Development/mcm/manifest.json /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmc/manifest.json
cp /Users/apple/Development/mcm/index.html /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmc/index.html
cd /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmc/
zip -r /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmc.zip *

# Mozilla Firefox
cp -R /Users/apple/Development/mcm/public/ /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmf/public/
cp /Users/apple/Development/mcm/manifestff.json /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmf/manifest.json
cp /Users/apple/Development/mcm/index.html /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmf/index.html
cd /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmf/
zip -r /Users/apple/Development/mcm_extension/mcmf.zip *
```

Comment: Does it  make a difference if you use `.` instead of `*` as the last arg of your `zip` command?

Comment: @BLayer No, everything is same.

Answer (score 0):

Current directory & parent directory are referred by `.` and `..` respectively.

So to zip the contents only excluding both current directory and parent directory try the following

```
zip -r /path_to_folder/* -x .. -x .
```

To excluding only parent directory and keep the current directory try

```
zip -r /path_to_folder/* -x ..
```

`-x` option is for excluding a file or directory while compressing with `zip`.

Comment: `*` does not match `.` or `..` (or any name starting with a dot) under normal conditions.